# How to specify parameters using .net core dependency injection?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, autofac

Consider this code using Autofac:

```
 Builder.RegisterType<SecurityCache>().As<ISecurityCache>()
    .WithParameter("id", AppId).SingleInstance()
```

`SecurityCache` has 3 parameters, two of which are handled by the DI container, and then the "id" parameter is specified using `WithParameter`. How can I do this with .NET Core DI, not using Autofac?

I want to do

```
services.AddSingleton<ISecurityCache, SecurityCache>();
```

But I am unsure how to specify the `id` parameter.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the implementation factory delegate when adding your service.

```
services.AddSingleton<ISecurityCache>(sp =>
    new SecurityCache(AppId, sp.GetService<IService1>(), sp.GetService<IService2>())
);
```

OR

```
services.AddSingleton<ISecurityCache>(sp =>
    ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<SecurityCache>(sp, AppId)
);
```

The delegate provides access to the service provider so you can resolve the other dependencies.

*From comments*

> In this solution, is `AppId` scoped and evaluated when `.AddSingleton` is called?

`AppId` in that case is evaluated as a constant when the factory delegate is invoked. It appears to be local to the function that registered the service.

Comment: Agreed, this is the best you can do with the "out of the box" Microsoft container. The Microsoft container is pretty lowest-common-denominator and will likely never have the features of Autofac, SimpleInjector, or other more robust containers.

Comment: In this solution, is `AppId` scoped and evaluated when `.AddSingleton` is called? If so, is there a way for Autofac to get a value passed into the `SecurityCache` constructor at instantiation time? I'm thinking of the case when you want the "factory" to have additional information only available at instantiation time.

Comment: @catfood `AppId` in that case is evaluated as a constant when the factory delegate is invoked. It appears to be local to the function that registered the service.